# can anyone know how to pass an id generated in one table to another table

Tags: mysql, yii

im having two tables,in the first table an userid is auto incremently generated when an user register and he/she click next they will move to the second table in which im trying to get the same userid registered in first table.

Comment: @kathik.p your question is unclear.Please post your code if you have tried.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php chek this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql then mysql_insert_id() is the function which gives you last inserted record id, if you are using mysqli then mysqli_insert_id() function gives you last inserted id. so do `$user_id = mysql_insert_id();` and then use $user_id variable

BTW its very basic question, rather than posting here, you should first prefer php manual OR mysql basic

Comment: what the problem with the code you given here? what you want to achieve with this code?